# How can I delete first word based on a condition and sort the list of strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a list of strings present in the below json format and I need to verify if the displayedString in the outer array is in the sorted order with a slight modification to the sorting logic.

```
{  
  "outer": [ 
            { "inner" : { "displayedString" : "The 40 AOI one"}
            { "inner" : { "displayedString" : "50 AOI one"},
            { "inner" : { "displayedString" : "The ABI one"}
            { "inner" : { "displayedString" : "AOI one"},
            { "inner" : { "displayedString" : "BOI one"},
            ]
}
```

The sorting logic has to be 0-9 < A-Z i.e, numbers take priority over the alphabets and also if the displayedString contains "The" as the first word, I need to remove/ignore it and continue with my sorting logic.
For example, in the above "The 40 AOI one" is prior to "50 AOI one" since "The" is removed and 4<5. similarly with "The ABI one" and "AOI one".
How can I verify the json input follows the logic provided?

Comment: Lexicographic sorting of strings already sorts numbers before letters, so you don't need to do anything special for that. So just use a regular expression to remove `The` at the beginning.

Comment: Do you also need numeric sorting, so that `5 < 10`?

Comment: Please show what you tried. We'll help you fix it, we won't write it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Sort a copy of your array and compare with original.

While sorting remove `The`  prefix with `/^the\s+/i` regular expression and adjust the collator options to your needs.

```js
const original = data.outer.map(({inner:{displayedString: str}}) => str);

console.log(JSON.stringify(original));

const compare = new Intl.Collator('en', {numeric:true}).compare;
const re = /^the\s+/i; // removes the first The

const valid = original.slice()
  .sort((a, b) => compare(a.replace(re,''),b.replace(re,'')))
  .every((item, idx) => item === original[idx]);
  

console.log('VALID SORTING:', valid);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script>
const data = {  
  "outer": [ 
            { "inner" : { "displayedString" : "The 40 AOI one"}},
            { "inner" : { "displayedString" : "50 AOI one"}},
            { "inner" : { "displayedString" : "The ABI one"}},
            { "inner" : { "displayedString" : "AOI one"}},
            { "inner" : { "displayedString" : "BOI one"}},
            ]
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a copy of your list,  define a custom sorting function to sort the list of strings based on the given criteria. Finally, you can compare the original list with the sorted list to check if they match.

```
    const json_data = `{
  "outer": [
    { "inner": { "displayedString": "The 40 AOI one" } },
    { "inner": { "displayedString": "50 AOI one" } },
    { "inner": { "displayedString": "The ABI one" } },
    { "inner": { "displayedString": "AOI one" } },
    { "inner": { "displayedString": "BOI one" } }
  ]
}`;

// Parse the JSON data
const data = JSON.parse(json_data);

// Extract the displayedString values
const displayedStrings = data.outer.map(item => item.inner.displayedString);

// Define a custom sorting function
function customSort(a, b) {
  // Helper function to remove "The " and convert to lowercase
  const normalizeString = str => str.toLowerCase().replace(/^the /, '');

  // Apply sorting logic
  const normalizedA = normalizeString(a);
  const normalizedB = normalizeString(b);

  if (normalizedA < normalizedB) return -1;
  if (normalizedA > normalizedB) return 1;
  return 0;
}

// Sort the displayed strings using the custom sorting function
const sortedStrings = displayedStrings.slice().sort(customSort);

// Check if the original list matches the sorted list
const isSorted = JSON.stringify(displayedStrings) === JSON.stringify(sortedStrings);

if (isSorted) {
  console.log("The JSON data follows the specified sorting logic.");
} else {
  console.log("The JSON data does not follow the specified sorting logic.");
}
```